# Take picture callback in Android custom camera application

Tags: android, callback, android-camera

I am developing a custom camera app in Android. My goal is to save a picture to file and open it in the fullscreen mode as soon as the file has been saved. Unfortuantely, the problem is that my main activity (ImageCapture) doesn't wait for ImageCaptureCallback results before calling the next activity (ImageDisplay).

To take a picture I am using a custom ImageCaptureCallback, which saves captured image to "tmpPicturePath" using OutputStream. Later the ImageDisplay activity is called - it reads the file saved in tmpPicturePath.

```
camera.takePicture(mShutterCallback, mPictureCallbackRaw, new ImageCaptureCallback(this));

// ImageCaptureCallback saves the file in tmpPicturePath

Intent intent = new Intent(ImageCapture.this, ImageDisplay.class);
intent.putExtra("tmpPicturePath", this.getTmpPicturePath());
startActivity(intent);
```

BUT the file that should be created in ImageCaptureCallback is not yet available at the moment of calling ImageDisplay activity. The overall effect is that not the actual but the previously taken picture is available in the ImageDisplay class. Do you have an idea how to handle this issue? In other words how to wait for callback results before calling the next activity?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample code for taking picture from camera

```
void selectPhoto() {

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, "New Picture");
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, "From your Camera");
    imageUri = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);

    startActivityForResult(intent, SELECT_PHOTO);
}
```

and in onActivityResult() method

```
            try {
                imageBitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), imageUri);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't see how this would solve the problem. I am an not calling a camera using an intent. Code quoted in the question is actually inside the ImageCapture activity, which is a custom built camera. I think that the question is: how to wait for callback results before calling the next activity?

Comment: Ok so need the working code for a custom camera using a sufaceView?

Comment: My Custom camera works OK. The problem is that results from ImageCaptureCallback are coming after ImageDisplay intent was initiated. This way in the ImageDisplay activity I always see the previously taken picture, not the actual one. Is there a way to make an activity wait for ImageCaptureCallback to fully process?

Comment: I don't think so that this can be achieved without a hack. So as a hack just change the `ImageView` image to default black image on camera start intent and when return from that intent just show a progress dialog until the callback is completed :)

Comment: Thanks Ali. I've managed to solve the problem :) In the ImageCaptureCallback I am calling a function this.processPicture() which triggers the Inent that opens ImageDisplay activity. Works!